# Laravel getting information from other table

Tags: laravel

I have the following tables user table, post table and profile table. the post belongs to a user and the profile belongs to a user. I also have a forum were people can post I want the users username to show instead of their name. But The username is in the profiles table and I don't know how to get it.

here is my code

```
    class Post extends Model
{
    //
     public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','posted_by');
    }

    class Profile extends Model
{
    //
      public function users(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','whos_profile');


    }


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname','lastname', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
   public function profile(){
      return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }

    public function post(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

}`enter code here`
```

Comment: have you already set up relationships? please read the documentation first, it is plentiful.

Comment: a user can have many profiles?

Comment: @Wreigh my fault I fixed it. hasOne not hasMany. so how do go about showing everything that the user has for everyone to see

Comment: simple. `$user->profile`, it will be null if the user has no profile, else it will return a profile object; from there you can access its attributes.

Comment: oh ok I understand. But quick question. In my controller I will do something like this correct?       $user=User::OrderBy('created_at','desc')->take(2)->get();

Comment: you will have a collection of users, make sure to access `profile` for each user, not on the collection.

Comment: It works I did 
 {{$u->profile}}
 but I am trying to get something specific like the user it dont work i did $u->profile->username and I get error message

Comment: what error message did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it as follows

```
$user = User::find($id);
if($user->profile){
   echo $user->profile->username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$rsltUsers = User::with(['profile','post'])->where('id',$id)->get();

foreach($rsltUsers as $rsltUsers){

  dd($user->profile->username);

}
```